# How to pass a vector as a method arguement?

Tags: java

I have a servlet which gets variables from a form and stores them in a vector.

I want to pass the whole vector to a method in another java class.

How am I supposed to do for that?

This is what I have tried:

In servlet-

```
private DbUpdate dbup = new DbUpdate(); 
int j=0;

Vector<String> v = new Vector<String>();
v.addElement("name");
v.addElement("profession");

Enumeration vEnum = v.elements();
j = dbup.insertValues(vEnum);
```

DbUpdate.java class

```
public int insertValues(Enumeration vc) {
    for (int j=1; j<14; j++) {
        statement.setString(j, vc.get(j));
    }
    i = statement.executeUpdate();
}
```

It says I cannot have `vc.get()` method here.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint:  it's the same approach you use for the `Enumeration`.

Comment: see also [Enumeration javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Enumeration.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's really strange why you are still using such kind of obsolete classes even you are using JDK 1.5+.

Use `List` instead.

```
List<String> params = Arrays.asList("name", "profession");
// if you prefer you can also create an ArrayList<String>() and add it one by one

dbUp.insertValues(params);
```

and in you DbUpdate.java, do something like

```
public int insertValues(Collection<String> params){
    int i = 0;
    for (String param : params){
        statement.setString(++i, param);
    }
    return statement.executeUpdate();
}
```

---

**Edit:**

If in any case you really really want to use `Enumeration`, you need to understand `Enumeration` works similar to an `Iterator` which provide you an interface to iterate through a collection of object.  Hence it should look something like:

```
public int insertValues(Enumeration<String> params){ // or use Enumeration<?>, but you need 
                                                     // further casting below
    int j = 0;
    while (params.hasMoreElements()) {
        String param = params.nextElement();
        statement.setString(++j, param);
    }
    return statement.executeUpdate();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you iterate all elements of enum, you can use below code

```
for(Enumeration e : vc.values())
```

Comment: Are you sure? Enumeration here have nothing to do with enum

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over `Enumeration` using following two methods,

```
hasMoreElements()
Tests if this enumeration contains more elements.
```

```
nextElement()
Returns the next element of this enumeration if this enumeration 
object has at least one more element to provide.
```

You need to modify your `insertValues()` method,

```
 public int insertValues(Enumeration vc){  
            while(vc.hasMoreElements()){                
             if(j<14){  
                statement.setString(j, vc.get(j));  
                 j++;               
             }  
           }  
           i = statement.executeUpdate();       
      return 0; // return what you want to return       
 }
```